# How to convert hours and minutes to minutes with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I need to convert hours and minutes in minutes values. With pure JavaScript Date object I do the following:

```
var d = new Date();
var minutes = d.getHours() * 60 + d.getMinutes();
```

I've just switched to [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and looking for better solution likes the following:

```
var minutes = moment(new Date()).toMinutes()
```

Is there is something like this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think your best bet is to create a `Duration` and then get the minutes using `asMinutes`.  This is probably clearer when describing an interval of time.

```
moment.duration().asMinutes()
```

[Here is the reference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/) in the docs.

Comment: Is it possible to use duration on existing moment,js object like moment(new Date()).duration().asMinutes() ?

Comment: I do think this is possible, but haven't tried it myself.

Comment: You are very smart!

Comment: @Erik no it's not possible.  You'll get: moment(...).duration is not a function

Comment: you need to put the input value inside the duration function as parameter. like

moment.duration(input_value).asMinutes()

Answer (score 14):

For those seeking to get minutes from an existing `Moment` object, you can first format it to whatever you need, then use `duration` to get its duration in minutes:

```
moment.duration(myMomentObjectToConvert.format("HH:mm")).asMinutes()
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use:

```
var m = moment(new Date());
var minutes = (m.hour()*60) + m.minute();
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/

Comment: @DavinTryon The edit made by the OP makes sense now.

Comment: moment() is equal to moment(new Date())

Answer (score 3):

I didn't needed moment.js, at least worked for my scenarios:

```js
console.log('converting 2 hours, 20 minutes and 120 seconds to minutes');

var hours = 2,
  minutes = 20,
  seconds = 120,
  timeInminutes = (hours * 60) + minutes + (seconds / 60);

console.log('2 hours, 20 minutes and 120 seconds to minutes is', timeInminutes, ' minutes')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const moment = require('moment')
var date = new Date()
console.log(date) // 2018-11-09T10:01:33.131Z

// 1.
console.log( 'object', moment(new Date()).toObject() )
// { years: 2018,
// months: 10,
// date: 9,
// hours: 13,
// minutes: 1,
// seconds: 33,
// milliseconds: 135 }

// 2.
console.log( 'array', moment(new Date()).toArray() ) // array [ 2018, 10, 9, 13, 1, 33, 141 ]

// 3.
console.log( 'year', moment(new Date()).toObject().years ) // year 2018
console.log( 'day of month', moment(new Date()).toObject().date ) // day of month 9
console.log( 'hours', moment(new Date()).toObject().hours ) // hours 13
console.log( 'minutes', moment(new Date()).toObject().minutes ) // minutes 1
console.log( 'seconds', moment(new Date()).toObject().seconds ) // seconds 33
console.log( 'milliseconds', moment(new Date()).toObject().milliseconds ) // milliseconds 139

// 4.
console.log( 'weeks', moment(new Date()).weeks() ) // weeks 45
console.log( 'day of week', moment(new Date()).days() ) // day of week 5
console.log( 'day of month', moment(new Date()).date() ) // day of month 9
console.log( 'hours', moment(new Date()).hours() ) // hours 13
console.log( 'minutes', moment(new Date()).minutes() ) // minutes 1
console.log( 'seconds', moment(new Date()).seconds() ) // seconds 33
console.log( 'milliseconds', moment(new Date()).milliseconds() ) // milliseconds 141
```

Answer (score 2):

just for simplification --
'07:07:00' is in HH:mm:ss format and this will be converted in minutes

`moment.duration('07:07:00').asMinutes()`