# Bootstrap Datetimepicker get time part as long

Tags: javascript, time, timestamp, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using BS Datetimepicker with Timeformat. My goal is to get the selected time, for example 8:30am, as a duration (long).

`timepicker.data('DateTimePicker').date()` returns a Moment, but this Moment also includes the Date dimension (current day), so if I then use `Moment.valueOf()` I'm not getting what I want.

The solution I have in mind would be getting `(Moment.hours() * 60 + Moment.minutes()) * 60 * 1000`, but I don't like it.

Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: What datetimeoicker are you using? Can you edit your question showing the code you use to init datetimepicker and what you tried to do?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454975/how-to-convert-hours-and-minutes-to-minutes-with-moment-js

Comment: I have separated date and time pickers, i needed to get a long from those two. Your second solution is good, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here two possible solutions:

- Get the [`startOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) the day and then calculate the difference in millisecond using [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)
- Build a [moment duration object](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) from [`hour`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/hour/) and [`minute`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/) of the selected time and then showing it [`asMilliseconds`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/milliseconds/)

Here a live sample:

```js
var timepicker = $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
  format: 'HH:mm'
});

$('#btn1').click(function(){
  // Get selected time
  var dateSelected = timepicker.data('DateTimePicker').date();
  if( !dateSelected ) return;
  // Get start of the day
  var startDay = dateSelected.clone().startOf('day');
  // Get difference (millseconds) from the start of the day and the selected time
  var duration = dateSelected.diff(startDay);
  console.log(duration);
});

$('#btn2').click(function(){
  // Get selected time
  var dateSelected = timepicker.data('DateTimePicker').date();
  if( !dateSelected ) return;
  // Create duration from hours and minutes slected
  var duration = moment.duration({
    h: dateSelected.hours(),
    m: dateSelected.minutes()
  });
  // Print duration as milliseconds
  console.log(duration.asMilliseconds());
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<button id="btn1" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Get date as duration V.1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Get date as duration V.2</button>
```