# Get the total number of minutes of a STRING with format hh:mm in javascript

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs, duration

```
var duration = '01:30';
```

How do you get its equivalent number of minutes which is 90mins?

I am using Moment JS

Here is the rest of my code:

```
var date = new Date();
var acqBrk = duration.split(':');
var mins = moment(date.setHours(parseInt(acqBrk[0]),parseInt(acqBrk[1]),0,0));
```

`mins` only gets the Moment type of `01:30` and not as string anymore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert hours and minutes to minutes with moment.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454975/how-to-convert-hours-and-minutes-to-minutes-with-moment-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct the moment duration object and call [`asMinutes`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/) on it:

```
moment.duration('01:30', 'HH:mm').asMinutes()
```

See a working demo below:

```js
console.log(
  moment.duration('01:30', 'HH:mm').asMinutes()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why do I have this error: Argument of type '"HH:mm"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Diff'.

Comment: @Char -- There is something else, which is wrong with your code. See the demo snippet in my answer, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you'd complete the task following how you started (simple string parsing):

```js
const duration = '01:30';
const durArr = duration.split(':');

console.log(`${durArr[0]*60 + durArr[1]*1} mins`);
```