# Why am I getting the wrong minutes from duration?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I wrote a component with a timer. Two values are transferred to it - the start and end times, from which I get the difference:

```js
const differenceTime = this.endTime - this.startTime
```

Values are passed in correctly, because:

```js
console.log(
  duration,
  duration.minutes(),
  duration.asMinutes()
)
```

It shows:

```
Duration {_isValid: true, _milliseconds: 3931000, _days: 0, _months: 0, _data: {…}, …}
5
65.51666666666667
```

That is, it proves that my code and values are generally correct. Then why does the `minutes()` method pass some kind of trimmed number? When it was 69 minutes, this method showed 9. When it was 68 minutes, this method showed 8.

Comment: Read the manual: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [How to convert hours and minutes to minutes with moment.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454975/how-to-convert-hours-and-minutes-to-minutes-with-moment-js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert hours and minutes to minutes with moment.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454975/how-to-convert-hours-and-minutes-to-minutes-with-moment-js)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `minutes()`, it will literally return your minutes value. That means, if you have time of 1 hour and 5 minutes (65 minutes in total), it will just return 5.

Comment: This is more of comment then the actual answer to the question. and there are duplicates for this question already please check the comments before answering :)

Comment: I think this answers the OP question, although it could be expanded a bit to make it clearer